# Content scrolling on mobile page with fixed header/footer

Tags: css, mobile, css-position

Hello i am building a mobile webpage where my content only will be scrolling and my footer and header is position:fixed - Can i make the content so that it doesn't scroll under the header or footer , so that it just scrolls in it's own div.

The reason why i want to do this is that i am going to have some opacity on my header and footer and if the content gets scrolled under , it's just not looking good.

Heres a jsfiddle i made to just show you the example of the scroll

http://jsfiddle.net/VNVqs/

Comment: You should remove all position absolute & give a fixed-height to scroll-content or wrapper with overflow auto. And remove position fixed from header & footer. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/VNVqs/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you are:

> **http://jsfiddle.net/VNVqs/3/**

I just removed the `position: absolute` to the scrolling part (*wrapper* and *scroll-content*), and added some `padding` to the wrapper in order to let the first and last item not being under header and footer.

Basically, the trick is done by using `position: fixed` **only on header and footer**, and let **the rest of the page to scroll as a normal page**, without using `overflow: auto` on a specific fixed-height element. Doing this way, the only problem is that the first lines of your content will be always under the fixed-positioned header (and last ones under the footer), but you can fix this by applying some padding on the content wrapper, as much as header (and footer) height. You got it?

Comment: Thanks but the content still gets under the heading and footer - maybe i was a bit vague in explaining the problem. i added some opacity to the header and footer. i just don't want any of the content to be able to be scrolled under either the header or footer - is it possible?

http://jsfiddle.net/VNVqs/4/

Comment: I updated my answer, also the example link. See Fiddle's *rev. 3*.

Comment: Yeah - First and last items are okay - but WHEN you are scrolling , the items are getting "behind" the header. that's my problem haha!
I just changed the opacity on the header and footer just to show that when the page getting scrolled the items gets behind the element.

Comment: @Fruxelot Ok, so I did not understood well. I think you will searching exactly for this. So, your **[first example](http://jsfiddle.net/VNVqs/)** seems already ok to me. The content scrolls on its own and does not go under header or footer... What am I missing?

Comment: Wow... i must be plain stupid - it works... haha.
Thanks for the help thou!