# Stop scrollbars showing over header/footer with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm creating an application using PhoneGap and the jQuery Mobile Framework. Sorry I can't provide a better screenshot, I can't reveal the content for legal reasons. You will see however that the scroll bar is over the header part of the application and the footer. I want the user to only be able to scroll through the main content area (the list view). If anybody with jQuery mobile experience could help me out I'd highly appreciate it.

I am using an unedited version of jQuery Mobile 1.3.1.

Thanks

Image:

[image]

Comment: Add some code or a live example so we can see what you're missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
position:absolute; 
z-index:1;
width:100%;
padding:0;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
overflow:auto;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VNVqs/

Not mine though, just a bookmarked link

Comment: Here is the original stackoverflow post with the authors' explanations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893404/content-scrolling-on-mobile-page-with-fixed-header-footer (I will test on multiple mobile devices today and tell you what I find)